# Making android listview layout scrollable

Tags: java, android, user-interface, listview, layout

I have an xml file that has the layout in ASCII form:

```
---------------
| ImageView
--------------
| TextView
--------------
| List...
--------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.some.app"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/MovieCover"
android:layout_width="100dip"
android:layout_height="100dip"
/> 
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/TextHeader"
    android:background="#000000">
</TextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </ListView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm having a problem displaying the layout when my ImageView and TextView takes up more than 3/4 of the screen. How do I make ImageView and TextView scrollable with the ListView that is being displayed? At this point of time, only the ListView to be scrolled and I want the entire layout to be scrollable as though they are one page on its own.

How can I do that?

Comment: Ideally putting the entire layout inside a scrollview should work, but android guidelines say not to put ListView inside a ScrollView, curious to know solution for this hence voting up !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<ScrollView>` as your layout container

something along the line of

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
    // your layout here
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the reason why we need the LinearLayout inside is that ScrollView can only have one direct child

Answer (score 1):

Butter to use two LinearLayout with `layoutweight="1"` and put ScrollView in one and listview in other

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                          <!-- scroll view content -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

ListView has addtoHeader and addtoFooter function. Make a separate layout and add it into header of ListView . In your case make a relative layout of imageview and textview and add it to the header of listview. The entire page will start scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the ImageView and TextView in a layout and putting this layout inside a ScrollView.?